# Changing Figure numbering

Tags: floats

I need to submit to a journal, separate files for each figure. I can submit figure 1. When I create the file for figure 2, the figure is automatically numbered "Figure 1". How can I begin numbering with "Figure 2"?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Maybe they only want the graphic file in a separate file, not the figure environment with its caption and label?

Answer (score 1):

We found the answer:

```
\setcounter{figure}{1}
```

will label the next figure "Figure 2"